# GStreamer - How to compose three streams (two video files with audio)

Tags: gstreamer

I have two avi files (one contains only video and the second file consists of video and audio stream). I would like to composite/mix two avi files to one video file (side by side) and preserve audio.

I can compose video streams (using videomixer) but I don't know how to add audio stream:

`gst-launch filesrc location=test01.avi ! decodebin ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 ! videobox border-alpha=0 left=-640 ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! queue ! avimux ! filesink location=videoTestMix666.avi filesrc location=test02.avi ! decodebin ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480 ! videobox right=-640 ! mix.`

Could you advice me hot to do this - how to add audio? Many thanks